# Can’t find a docker image of kafka-connect for arm64 that can convert avro file to parquet format

Tags: parquet, avro, apache-kafka-connect, arm64, docker-image

I have a m1 chip (arm64) and I want to use kafka-connect to convert Avro files to Parquet format and send them to s3.
I got this error:

```
[2022-10-03 10:59:02,362] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=sink-s3-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:611)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:333)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:234)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:203)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:243)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/FileOutputFormat
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:95)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.<init>(ParquetWriter.java:285)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter$Builder.build(ParquetWriter.java:675)
    at io.confluent.connect.s3.format.parquet.ParquetRecordWriterProvider$1.write(ParquetRecordWriterProvider.java:102)
    at io.confluent.connect.s3.format.S3RetriableRecordWriter.write(S3RetriableRecordWriter.java:46)
    at io.confluent.connect.s3.format.KeyValueHeaderRecordWriterProvider$1.write(KeyValueHeaderRecordWriterProvider.java:107)
    at io.confluent.connect.s3.TopicPartitionWriter.writeRecord(TopicPartitionWriter.java:562)
    at io.confluent.connect.s3.TopicPartitionWriter.checkRotationOrAppend(TopicPartitionWriter.java:311)
    at io.confluent.connect.s3.TopicPartitionWriter.executeState(TopicPartitionWriter.java:254)
    at io.confluent.connect.s3.TopicPartitionWriter.write(TopicPartitionWriter.java:205)
    at io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkTask.put(S3SinkTask.java:234)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:581)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 31 more
```

Although this issue has been raised [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/issues/553) already, I have not found a solution.

Comment: I am also having same issue. How did you solve this issue